# Volume of A Cone: I Don't Know Why This Is Wrong,

Tags: geometry, volume

On a question it says find the volume of a cone. The height is 9m and the radius is 5.8m. I got the answer of 317 (rounded), but the answer was wrong and it says the correct answer was 79. When I went to check on calculators even online calculators it kept saying 317.05. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong? Thank you so much.

Edit: I figured it out, the issue was the radius that was given was the whole base and was meant to be divided in half and I forgot to divide the radius. That's how they got 79.

Comment: volume of silinder divided by $3$

Comment: "radius that was given was the whole base". That is called the *diameter*, not *radius*. If they called it the "radius", then the error is still theirs, not yours.